# I got message for error_log file "The stream or file ".../laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: laravel

> Tue Jun 20 13:17:41.195156 2017] [:error] [pid 14454] [client 203.131.216.144:60475]
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/html/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in
>
> /var/www/html/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0
>
> /var/www/html/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1
>
> /var/www/html/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(336): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2
>
> /var/www/html/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(615): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#3
>
> /var/www/html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#4
>
> /var/www/html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->writeLog('er in
>
> /var/www/html/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107, referer: http://203.131.209.179/app/login

Comment: Have you give the permissions to storage logs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Directory Permissions
>
> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#installing-laravel

So, for example, in Linux you can do this by executing `chmod` command:

```
chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer. I set the permissions and am still getting permission denied on laravel.log.

Comment: @JayBienvenu instead of downvoting you could try to find a problem in your system and add your own answer. This solution perfectly works for me for years (Linux, Mac OS).

Comment: That's what I've spent most of this afternoon doing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The resolution was to set it to 777 instead of 755.

Comment: Hey , i have the same problem with Symfony 4.4 ( Windows 10) ; any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

In your project directory run this command:

`chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: This is a dangerous way of solving this because you are proposing to grant all the permissions on all the users on the system, on that situation alway the right way it to dig deeper into logs and code trying to understand why is getting a `Permission denied` error.

Comment: Do not set permission 777 on any web server.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick fix**: Remove `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command for giving the right permissions to the storage folder that involves `logs/laravel.logs`

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage
```

If you are using windows the 775 means :

> owner group other
>
> rwx   rwx   r_x