# Deploy Laravel on Google App Engine - Flexible

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, laravel-6

After deploying Laravel 6 to Google App Engine, got this error when run the url `https://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/`.

`The stream or file "/app/storage/logs/laravel-2019-12-31.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`

[image]

I have followed the instrucation given on https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible[2](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)

Here is my **app.yaml** file

```
runtime: php  # language of the app
env: flex     # let app engine know we use flexible environment
runtime_config:
 document_root: .   #folder where index.php is
# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
 - .env #we want to skip this to make sure we don’t mess stuff up on the server
env_variables:
 # Put production environment variables here.
 APP_ENV: production   # or production
 APP_DEBUG : true # or false 
 APP_KEY: YOUR_API_KEY
#go to generate app key paragraf in this tutorial
 CACHE_DRIVER: database
# instead of putting the cache in the database I recommend using redis
 SESSION_DRIVER: database #or file since both work
 APP_LOG: errorlog
 APP_TIMEZONE: UTC #your timezone of choice
# follow the part of the tutorial on setting up your SQL database
 DB_CONNECTION: mysql
 DB_HOST: localhost
 DB_DATABASE: XXX
 DB_USERNAME: XXX
 DB_PASSWORD: XXX
 DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME
 QUEUE_DRIVER: database #in case you execute queued jobs
 MAIL_DRIVER: mail
 MAIL_HOST: smtp.sparkpostmail.com
 MAIL_PORT: 587
 MAIL_USERNAME: null
 MAIL_PASSWORD: null
 LOG_DELETE:  true # this is a parameter added by us in the project .env file. You can add here any setting you would add to your .env file
 GOOGLE_VISION_PROJECT_ID : PROJECT_ID
#we need this for the flex environment
beta_settings:
   # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
   # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
   cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME"
```

**composer.json**

```
"scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
           "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
           "@php artisan optimize",
           "chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap\/cache"
       ],
       "post-update-cmd": [
           "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
           "@php artisan optimize"
       ]
    }
```

I have Tested on local machine and its working successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In the App Engine Flex environment you can't write files because the file system is read only. There is neat solution though since you can integrate [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) into Laravel.

You need to execute the following command:

```
composer require google/cloud-logging google/cloud-error-reporting
```

Additionally you need to change the `report` function in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file:

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['GAE_SERVICE'])) {
        Bootstrap::init();
        Bootstrap::exceptionHandler($exception);
    } else {
        parent::report($exception);
    }
}
```

At the top of the file you need to add `use Google\Cloud\ErrorReporting\Bootstrap;`

In your `app.yaml` you need to add the following to the `env_variables`:

```
LOG_CHANNEL: stackdriver
```

In the `logging.php` you need to add the following to the `'channels'` array:

```
'stackdriver' => [
    'driver' => 'custom',
    'via' => App\Logging\CreateStackdriverLogger::class,
    'level' => 'debug',
],
```

The last thing you need to do is create the `CreateStackdriverLogger` class in the `app/Logging` directory:

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Google\Cloud\Logging\LoggingClient;
use Monolog\Handler\PsrHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class CreateStackdriverLogger
{
    /**
     * Create a custom Monolog instance.
     *
     * @param array $config
     * @return \Monolog\Logger
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        $logName = isset($config['logName']) ? $config['logName'] : 'app';
        $client = new LoggingClient([
            'projectId' => 'YOUR-PROJECT-ID'
        ]);

        $psrLogger = $client->psrLogger($logName);

        $handler = new PsrHandler($psrLogger);
        $logger = new Logger($logName, [$handler]);

        return $logger;
    }
}
```

Now all your logs go to the Stackdriver system.

Answer (score 0):

> The stream or file "/app/storage/logs/laravel-2019-12-31.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668311/i-got-message-for-error-log-file-the-stream-or-file-laravel-log-could-not), the reason behind this error could be because of `directory permissions`:

> Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

You will find more information about it following this two posts:

- **Post 1:** [How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened/23412543#23412543)
- **Post 2:** [I got message for error_log file “The stream or file ”…/laravel.log“ could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668311/i-got-message-for-error-log-file-the-stream-or-file-laravel-log-could-not)

I hope it helps.